# Keep asking me to declare scalar variable. Here is my code and i have no idea how it goes about it

Tags: c#, html, sql-server-2008

```
SqlConnection connection = null;
SqlCommand command = null;
SqlDataReader dataReader = null;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {   //first time access to this page, clear all the textboxes
        staffIdTextBox.Text = "";
        passwordTextBox.Text = "";
        messageLabel.Text = "";
    }
}
protected void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{//When user keep in the button
    try
    {
        string staffId = "";
        string password = "";
        string role = "";
         //retrieve connectionString from web.config file
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FacilityDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        //create connection with database specified in the connectionString
        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        //Open database connection
        connection.Open();
        //prepare sql statements
        string sql = "Select * from Staff where StaffId= @staffId" +" and" + " Passwd= @passwd" + " and" + " Role= @role";
        command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        //Execute
        dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
        //Declaration of scalar variable ???
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staffId",staffId);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passwd", password);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", role);


        string staffId2 = staffIdTextBox.Text;
        string password2 = passwordTextBox.Text;
        bool staffExist = false;
        //call method to check for valid staff
        staffExist = checkValidUser(staffId2, password);
        if (staffExist == true)
        {
            Session.Add("@StaffId", staffId2);
            Server.Transfer("Default.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            messageLabel.Text = "Incorrect username or password, please try again";
        }
    }
//If error happen
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error Message:" + ex.Message);
        }
        //cleanup object
        finally
        {
            if (connection != null)
                connection.Close();
        }

    }
// check if user exist in the database
    private bool checkValidUser(string staffId, string password)
        {
        bool validStaff = false;
            if (staffId == "@staffId" && password == "@password")
            {
                validStaff = true;
            }
            return validStaff;
        }
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have the faintest idea of what is going on here, do you?

Comment: Yeah, i am pretty new to coding. started 2 months ago

Comment: Well, if _you_ don't understand your code at all, I don't think someone else is going to try and make sense of it for you. Just saying.

Comment: I do understand them, but they keep asking me to declare scalar variable for the sql statement. I just cant understand that part. after linking up to database and sql statement declaration. As well the private bool checkValidUser is wrong too, but i do not know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are executing your reader before you're adding your parameters:

```
string sql = "Select * from Staff where StaffId= @staffId" +" and" + " Passwd= @passwd" + " and" + " Role= @role";
command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
//Execute
dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();  <-- EXECUTING 
//Declaration of scalar variable ???
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staffId",staffId); <-- PARAMETERS
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passwd", password);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", role);
```

should likely be:

```
string sql = "Select * from Staff where StaffId= @staffId" +" and" + " Passwd= @passwd" + " and " + " Role= @role";
command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
//Declaration of scalar variable ???
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staffId",staffId);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passwd", password);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", role);
//Execute
dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
```